# How to identify a dynamic input checkbox element through xpath using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, string-interpolation, f-string

Hello I need some help i'm using python last version with selenium.
I can't reach an element input checkbox.
Here is the input :

```html
<div class="info info13">
  <input type="checkbox" name="yachi13" id="yachi13" class="input-checkbox" value="13">
</div>
```

I tried this :

```py
# try 1
swClick(driver, 'xpath', "[//*@id='yachi" + teethValue + "']")
# try 2
driver.find_element_by_id("yachi" + teethValue)
# try 3
swClick(driver, 'xpath', "[//input[@name='yachi" + teethValue + "']")
# try 4
swClick(driver, 'xpath', "//div[@class='info info" + teethValue + " canClick']/input[@id='yachi" + teethValue + "']")
# try 5
swClick(driver, 'xpath', "//div[@class='info info" + teethValue + "']")
# try 6
for i in range(10):
  try:
      driver.find_element_by_xpath(
      "//input[@id='yachi" + teethValue + "']"
      ).click()
      break
  except NoSuchElementException as e:
      print('Retry in 1 second')
      time.sleep(1)
  else:
      raise e
```

The teethvalue is a number, and the swClick a function and work perfecly .
Can you show me how to handle the checkbox with a classic way ?
Thank you !

Comment: Nope :/ but I can share more of the code html @Prophet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) also known as [f-string Formatting](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/f-string-formatting-in-python) as follows:

```
teethValue = "13"
print(f"//input[@name='yachi{teethValue}']")
```

Output:

```
//input[@name='yachi13']
```

Effectively, your code block will be:

```
# teethValue = "13"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//input[@name='yachi{teethValue}']").click()
```

Comment: I'm so sad, it don't work, thank you for your clear msg !
I get no error msg, I also try with this following code:  driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//input[@name='yachi{teethValue}']")
And I try to print it , but nothing too

Comment: It working, I tried to handle with the wrong tag. So I pointed on the div.
Like this: 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='info info{teethValue} canClick']").click()
Thanks you @DebanjanB ! I learned a new way to proceed!